# SwiftyJSON can't get to string

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

What am I doing wrong here. I'm using SwiftyJSON. The first line prints the correct value. I get an error at the second line saying: Could not find member string. Shouldn't I be able to get the string value here?

```
println(json["weather"][0]["description"])    // prints the correct value
if let description = json["weather"][0]["description"].string {
    self.descriptionLabel.text = description
}
```

Comment: why are you doing .string?? Just do `let description = json["weather"][0]["description"]`

Comment: you're probably calling .string on a string which won't work, remove .string

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
descriptionLabel.text = json["weather"][0]["description"].stringValue
```